# How to find what files / directories are not copied yet?

Tags: file-management

I found the following 'nice' situation:

1. An archive of few disks (actually three disks) which has a bunch of photos (more or less) organized. Well, this is good.
2. A big disk shared on a network which has a bunch of photos which has *another* folder structure (even if is somewhat recognizable for a human being) than the archive described above, but **some** of the files on this big network share are the same with the files from the archive. Well, this is bad.

What we need is to move the different (**new**) files from the network share in the archive (perhaps we'll use for this a new disk added to archive).

The program that we need is different from a regular File Duplicate Finder program because usually the File Duplicate Finder finds the duplicates from all sources comparing each file with another. We want to find the *differences* between the two sources.

It is fine for us to have a report generated in text file which after this we'll use to do our move. A Windows solution will be preferred.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can compare folders and give you a list of differences. It even has options to copy over files that exist in one folder, but not the other. [Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/) is another program that allows you to sync folders and files and could also be used for what you want to do.

Both are free software, and run on Windows.

Comment: it has different directory structures

Answer (score 0):

Since it are different directories maybe the easiest is to just copy the disks to a folder \disks on the share. Then install Google Picassa and choose "look for duplicates".

It make it very easy to identify the duplicates in the directory \disks.

Then you can even remove the duplicates and move the correct photo's to the correct physical folders in Picasa.